# jQuery AJAX POST to Rails 3.2.1 Params won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to send an AJAX request to my rails controller (the `make_suggestion` method in the `items controller`).

I have the following javascript:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/items/make_suggestion",   // pass to make_suggestions in recipes controller
  type: "POST",     
  dataType: 'json', 
  data: parsed_data // a Javascript object/data hash
});
```

With debug(params) on, I'm not seeing any of the parsed_data in the params.

Can anyone please point out what is wrong?  And how do I create symbols in the params in Rails through firing AJAX?

---

**UPDATES**

In my controller, I have

```
def make_suggestion
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html 
        format.json { render :json => params }
    end
end
```

My ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:3000/items/make_suggestion",   // I'm doing the proper routing later, since '/make_suggestion' routes to 'items/1/make_suggestion'
  type: "POST",     
  dataType: 'json', 
  data: parsed_data,
  success: function(returned_value){
            if(returned_value)
                alert('true');
            $('.test').append(returned_value);
        }, 
  error: function(returned_value){
        $('.test').html('<p>Error in AJAX request</p>');
        alert('Not working');
  }
});
```

And my parsed_data looks like this:

> Parameters: {"data1"=>{"position"=>"1", "item_id"=>"item_1",
>   "to_do"=>"unknown ", "selected"=>"false"}, "data2"=>{"position"=>"2",
>   "item_id"=>"item_2", "to_do"
>   =>"unknown", "selected"=>"false"}, "data3"=>{"position"=>"3", "item_id"=>"item_3 ", "to_do"=>"unknown", "selected"=>"false"},
>   "data4"=>{"position"=>"4", "item_id "=>"item_4", "to_do"=>"unknown",
>   "selected"=>"false"}, "data5"=>{"position"=>"5" , "item_id"=>"item_5",
>   "to_do"=>"unknown", "selected"=>"false"}}

But when I went to /items/make_suggestion.json, it's only showing the following:

> {"action":"make_suggestion","controller":"recipes","format":"json"}

Comment: my guess is your `parsed_data` variable is null - try outputting it to the browser javascript console

Comment: looks like you are good to go? I am assuming `Parameters` output above is from your rails log? so just access any params data in your rails action as needed `params[:data1][:item_id] # => item_1`

Comment: the parsed_data has always been there, but the problem is I can't access the params data. The params hash doesn't contain any of the parsed_data (see the last line in the question)

Comment: not sure what you mean when you say "But when I went to /items/make_suggestion.json ..." do you mean you typed  "http://localhost:3000/items/make_suggestion.json" into the browser address bar?

Comment: yes that's what I meant

Comment: ok, so now compare the params written to the log between these 2 urls enterd into the browser address bar: http://localhost:3000/items/make_suggestion.json VS http://localhost:3000/items/make_suggestion.json?foo=FOO&bar=BAR

Comment: the latter has the additional "foo":"FOO","bar":"BAR" in the hash

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33862/discussion-between-house9-and-john-yeung)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view / trace parameters in multiple ways

1) tail your rails log file `tail -f log/development.log`, note that the rails web server usually starts tailing to the console once started

2) raise exceptions and view debug output in the browser

3) use the javascript console in your browser (some are built-in), also consider Firefox with Firebug plug (use the 'console') tab

**Tailing the rails log**

every single request made to your rails server will show all of the parameters passed, as well as the controller and action which received the request and all sql statements generated
consider adding the 'awesome_print' gem to your application for better logging output, once installed `logger.ap params` will give you a nice readable output

**Raise exceptions**

not needed very often but if you add `raise "ZOMG"` as the first line of your controller action, it will render html output and show all the parameters passed. This is almost useless for ajax calls

**Javascript Console**

This will show all ajax requests and all parameters that javascript is sending to the rails server and all data being returned as well, very useful

Rails will map the javascript ajax parameters to a ruby hash, this is very nice as these data structures are almost exactly the same in the browser as they are in rails, i.e.

```
// javascript data structure
var parsed_data = {
  foo: "FOO",
  bar: "BAR",
  person: {
    first_name: "Joe",
    last_name: "Smith"
  }
}
```

output to the log using awesome_print would result in a ruby hash something along the lines of

```
logger.ap params

{
   :foo => "FOO",
   :bar => "BAR",
   :person => {
    :first_name => "Joe",
     :last_name => "Smith"
   }
}

# access the data
params[:foo]
# => "FOO"
params[:person][:first_name]
# => "Joe"
```

Comment: thanks for the response and pointers, but the parsed_data isn't null, please see the update.

Answer (score 0):

Your data post to controller not detail.
look my example :

```
      $.ajax({
            url:'/contact/new',
            type:'get',
            data:{object_param:{
                first_name:'zainulmasadi',
                last_name:'masadi ganteng',
                phone_number:'089745674119541'}},
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(returned_value){
                if(returned_value)
                    alert('true');
            }
        })
```

and my controller

```
def new
    @contact = ContactPhone.create(params[:object_param])
    if @contact.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json {render :json => @contact}
      end
    end

  end
```

Comment: so am I supposed to be able to see the params hash in the debug(params)? If so, on which page?

Comment: I dont understand about your purpose..??
you can create same param with your model ..
I Hope solve :D

Comment: because I want to check if the data is actually received by the controller. right now in my code, the success function in .ajax() is being run, but then the data isn't there, i.e  params[:data1] is nil